# Delivering Server Side Windows exe application via Asp.net

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, iis-8

I have a strange requirement from a client that I have been battling with for weeks.

The client has a standalone Winform exe and web applications sitting on Windows 2012 Server. The Plan is to incorporate the exe application into the Web applications so that it can be rendered through the browser or called via a hyperlink. The exe application is portable. Web applications run on .NET framework 3.5,written in C#.

Due to high security restrictions on the server none of my attempts seem to work. When I click on the button on the page nothing happens.

I am now exploring delivering the exe application to end users via WebDAV. Any ideas would be helpful

**I have tried the following:**

On web.config I set the path.

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="EXELOC" value="C:\Temp\addons\"/>

</appSettings>
```

On the aspx page I have a button that calls the application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string locn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXELOC"];
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = locn + "Application.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();           

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I set permissions for IIS Application pool to access the folder where the exe is located:

```
$IncomingPath = "C:\Temp\Addons"
$Acl = Get-Acl $IncomingPath
$Ar = New-Object  system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("IIS AppPool\addons","FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $IncomingPath $Acl
```

I have also attempted to utilize URI:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Ach]
@="URL:Ach Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Ach\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Temp\\addons\\Application.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Ach\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Ach\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Ach\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Temp\\addons\\Application.exe\" /u \"%1\""
```

I have also attempted setting the application UNC and calling via Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("\\\\192.168.5.8\\Applications\\Application.bat", 1,false);
        }
    </script>
```

Nothing is working.

Comment: Do you want to distribute an application, like a download link in a web page? Or do you want to have a url scheme so when the user clicks on a link, it opens an app in the client and run it, like `mailto:`? Do you want the `app.exe` run on client-side or server-side?

Comment: Thank you for your response Reza.I want the app.exe to run on the server side and be presented to the client. When the user clicks the button on the aspx page ,it should invoke the app from server and present it to the user.

Comment: "I want the app.exe to run on the server side and be presented to the client" can only be implemented via things like Citrix virtual apps, https://www.citrix.com/products/citrix-virtual-apps-and-desktops/ Rather complicated and also requires client side installation. So no doubt your simple ideas won't work.

Comment: *I want the app.exe to run on the server side and be presented to the client* ... if you are sure this is the requirement, it means you need something like Citrix or Remote Desktop Services remote apps.

Comment: running the app should work easily once you set the required permissions. But displaying anything from a desktop app through the browser is not trivial sadly. Then web development would be super easy.

Answer (score 0):

It is time to tell the client that what he WANTS does not matter unless he is willing to pay for redeveloping a whole platform, which means tens of millions in costs. This simply is not how things work, regardless what he wants. .Exe files running on the server will not magically transfer their output to the browser.

Comment: thanks , actually had to rebuild the entire solution.